# Rather short SQL statement but with many long 'SUBSTRING' statements, can this be optimized better?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

This is part of a SELECT statement. The logic is pretty straightforward, however I feel like there's gotta be a way to shorten the 3rd and 4th lines.

The 'TR.xType' string will look something like "Users|true|null" most likely. Lines 3 and 4 are checking if that middle value 'true' in this case, is a valid boolean before using it.

```
CASE WHEN PD.DisplayModeRestricted = 1
THEN ISNULL(PD.DisplayOpenMode, 1)
ELSE CASE WHEN LOWER(SUBSTRING(TR.xType, CHARINDEX('|', TR.xType, 0) + 1, CHARINDEX('|', TR.xType, CHARINDEX('|', TR.xType, 0) + 1) - CHARINDEX('|', TR.xType, 0) - 1)) IN ('true', 'false')
    THEN LOWER(SUBSTRING(TR.xType, CHARINDEX('|', TR.xType, 0) + 1, CHARINDEX('|', TR.xType, CHARINDEX('|', TR.xType, 0) + 1) - CHARINDEX('|', TR.xType, 0) - 1))
    ELSE ISNULL(@displayOpenMode, ISNULL(PD.DisplayOpenMode, 1))
    END
END AS displayOpenMode,
```

I should mention this is on SQL Server 2014 :)

Comment: `TR.xType` should be a table all it's own rather than a single field containing multiple values.  That violates the principle rule of relational databases. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you really just want the input string parsed.

Starting in SQL 2016 you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql), otherwise there are many custom split implementations.

Both options are discussed [here](http://sqlhints.com/tag/split-string-to-an-array-in-sql/)

A lot will depend on whether your input string is consistent. (i.e. the same number of elements)

Answer (score 0):

There actual performance shouldn't be bad... It's just a little bit unwieldy and nested functions can be a real pain if you have to debug anything.

For that, you can actually use cross apply with a table constructor. Here is an example showing that you can accomplish the same thing and keep thing legible.

```
-- Something to test with...
CREATE TABLE #TestData ( DelimitedString VARCHAR(100) );
INSERT #TestData(DelimitedString) VALUES ('aaaaaaaaa|bbbbbbbbb|cccccccccc|ddddddddddd|eeeeeeeeeee|ffffff');
```

---

```
SELECT 
    Item_1 = SUBSTRING(td.DelimitedString, 1, ISNULL(c1.CharLocation -1, 100)), 
    Item_3 = SUBSTRING(td.DelimitedString, c2.CharLocation + 1, ISNULL(c3.CharLocation - c2.CharLocation - 1, 100)),
    Item_5 = SUBSTRING(td.DelimitedString, c4.CharLocation + 1, ISNULL(c5.CharLocation - c4.CharLocation - 1, 100))
FROM
    #TestData td -- adding WAY more than necessary to demonstrate how much easier it is to manage...
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', td.DelimitedString, 1), 0)) ) c1 (CharLocation)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', td.DelimitedString, c1.CharLocation + 1), 0)) ) c2 (CharLocation)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', td.DelimitedString, c2.CharLocation + 1), 0)) ) c3 (CharLocation)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', td.DelimitedString, c3.CharLocation + 1), 0)) ) c4 (CharLocation)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', td.DelimitedString, c4.CharLocation + 1), 0)) ) c5 (CharLocation)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', td.DelimitedString, c5.CharLocation + 1), 0)) ) c6 (CharLocation)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', td.DelimitedString, c6.CharLocation + 1), 0)) ) c7 (CharLocation)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', td.DelimitedString, c7.CharLocation + 1), 0)) ) c8 (CharLocation)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', td.DelimitedString, c8.CharLocation + 1), 0)) ) c9 (CharLocation);
```

---

Results...

```
Item_1       Item_3       Item_5
------------ ------------ ---------------
aaaaaaaaa    cccccccccc   eeeeeeeeeee
```

As you can see, it become very easy to simply pick out any element you'd like...